# How to send an image in a Client/Server architecture with Socket python

Tags: python, sockets, client-server

I'm trying to send an image from a server to a client using sockets in python. But when the client receives the image, I try to display it using Image() and Byteio(), but an error is displayed:

I tried to find out where this error was coming from, so I tried displaying the bit size of the image received on the client side and comparing it with the bit size of the image on the server side, and I realised that there was a difference. The bit size on the server side is greater than that on the client side. Maybe that's where the problem lies. If so, how do you deal with this problem? Or how do you transfer images through a client/server architecture in Python with sockets?

My server code:

```
import socket
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode
import json
from datetime import datetime
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image

host = 'localhost'
port = 50000

mySocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mySocket.bind((host, port))
mySocket.listen()

while 1:
    connexion, adresse = mySocket.accept()
    with open('WhatsApp Image 2023-10-16 at 17.49.56.jpeg', 'rb') as fichier_image:
        image = fichier_image.read()
    if type(image)==bytes:
        try:
            taile_image = len(image)
            print(taile_image)
            print(taile_image.to_bytes(4, byteorder='big'))
            connexion.sendall(taile_image.to_bytes(4, byteorder='big'))
            connexion.sendall(image)
        except:
            pass
    else:
        try:
            resultat_str = json.dumps(resultat, default=str)
            connexion.send(resultat_str.encode('utf8'))
        except:
            pass
    connexion.close()
    ch = input("<R>ecommencer <T>erminer ? ")
    if ch.upper() == "T":
        break
mySocket.close()
```

and this is my client code:

```
import socket, threading
import json
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image

host = 'localhost'
port = 50000

class ThreadEmission(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, conn):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.connexion = conn 

    def run(self):
        ident = 2
        pays='Guinée'
        msgClient = "SELECT logo FROM entreprise WHERE identreprise=%s"%ident
        self.connexion.send(msgClient.encode('utf8'))
        

class ThreadReception(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, conn):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.connexion = conn 
        self.resultat = None

    def run(self):
        
        #print(msgServeur)
        try:
            msgServeur = self.connexion.recv(1024).decode('utf8')
            self.resultat = json.loads(msgServeur)
        except :
            taille_image_bytes = self.connexion.recv(4)
            print('taille_image_bytes ',taille_image_bytes)
            taille_image = int.from_bytes(taille_image_bytes, byteorder='big')
            print('taille_image', taille_image)
            self.resultat= self.connexion.recv(taille_image)
            print(len(self.resultat))       
            #print (type(msgServeur))

        self.connexion.close()
        
    def get_resultat(self):
        return self.resultat
            

myClient = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
myClient.connect((host, port))

th_E = ThreadEmission(myClient)
th_R = ThreadReception(myClient)    
#th_E.start()
th_R.start()
#th_E.join()
th_R.join()
resultat = th_R.get_resultat()
print(resultat)

print(type(resultat))
image = Image.open(BytesIO(resultat))
image.show()
```

Comment: What's going on with the `if type(image)==bytes:`?  It will **always** be `bytes`.  And reading from the connection in the client and first assuming it is JSON will **steal** up to 1024 bytes from the image, raise an exception, then try to receive the image.  Note that `recv(taille_image)` will very likely receive less than the whole image.  `recv(n)` will receive 1-n bytes (or zero on connection close).  Keep reading until you have the total size, but first get rid of the try/except assuming JSON first.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Please modify my code and bring it back to me

Comment: @MarkTolonen In the early days, my server interacted with a database, the client sends a request to the server which in turn queries the database. The response from the database can be a byte file, which is why try/except is used. As I was encountering an error, I wanted to take an image and send it directly to see if I would get the same error, so when modifying my code, I left try/except

Comment: When asking a question, make a [mcve].  Remove useless code and focus on the problem.

Comment: Also, *everything* you receive from the socket is a "byte file".  Add header information about the type (e.g. "image" or "json") instead.  Note also that bare `except: pass` hides errors and should be removed when debugging or at least `except Exception as e: print(type(e), e)` to make the error visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a minimal example with the server sending one image on client connection and the client receiving the image.  As mentioned in the comments, the OP code had unrelated code to handle a possible JSON response that is outside the scope of the question and was interfering with reception of the image.

Note that `recv(n)` receives 1-n bytes or 0 on disconnect.  You are responsible for buffering data until you receive a complete message.  In this case make sure you read exactly four bytes for the length, then exactly "length" bytes for the data.  Using `socket.makefile` can help with buffering by wrapping the socket in a file-like object where `.read(n)` is available to read exactly n bytes unless an error or EOF (socket close) is encountered.

Server:

```py
import socket

with socket.socket() as sock:
    sock.bind(('', 50000))
    sock.listen()

    while True:
        client, addr = sock.accept()
        print(f'{addr}: connected')
        with open('some_image.jpg', 'rb') as file:
            image = file.read()
        with client:
            length = len(image)
            client.sendall(length.to_bytes(4, byteorder='big'))
            client.sendall(image)
        print(f'{addr}: disconnected')
```

Client:

```py
import socket
import threading
import io
from PIL import Image

with socket.socket() as sock:
    sock.connect(('localhost', 50000))
    with sock.makefile('rb') as infile:
        header = infile.read(4)
        if len(header) == 4:
            length = int.from_bytes(header, byteorder='big')
            image = infile.read(length)
            if len(image) == length:
                image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image))
                image.show()
            else:
                print('incomplete image')
        else:
            print('incomplete header')
```